# Insert form input value into href target URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting user input from a form and displaying this information in a span based on it's ID. How can I send this info to a  tag as well? I want this to display their email and make an mailto: link with the same input.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").keyup(update);
    });
    function update(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $('#DisplayEmail').html(email);
    }
    </script>

    <form>
        <input id="email" name="email" size="40" />
    </form>

    <a href="mailto:"><span id="DisplayEmail"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
function update(){
   var email = $("#email").val();
   $('#DisplayEmail')
    .html(email)
    .parent().attr('href', 'mailto:'+email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `span` (it's unncessary, since the `a` can contain the address as well), and give the ID to the link instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").keyup(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            $('#DisplayEmail').text(email).attr("href", "mailto:" + email);
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <input id="email" name="email" size="40" />
</form>

<a id="DisplayEmail" href=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function update(){
   var email = $("#email").val();
   $('#DisplayEmail')
    .html(email)
    .parent().attr('href', 'mailto:'+email);
}
```